# extracting string using javascript regex

Tags: javascript, regex

Given:
`"4 John Smith Rd., Pasadena 94786"` or
`"4 John Smith Rd., North Pasadena 94786".`

The following regex failed to extract the City in array index 0 and the zip code in array index.

**How to fix it?** thx

`doc.address.match(/, (\w+) +(\d{5})/g);`

Comment: Well, _kind of_ first of all, those postal codes are five digits in length.

Comment: Sorry, that was a typo

Comment: I thought probably so :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
var address = ["4 John Smith Rd., Pasadena 94786",
  "4 John Smith Rd., North Pasadena 94786"
]
for(var i in address){
 console.log(address[i].match(/, (.+)? +(\d{5})/));
}
```

group1 is city and group2 is the zip code.

Answer (score 0):

If `match` is successful, the captures will begin at the first index. Try:

```
var result = docs.address.match(/, ([\w ]+) (\d{5})/i);
var city = result[1];
var zip = result[2];
```

But this is pretty naïve address parsing. There are libraries dedicated to this.

Comment: This doesn't work for the data in the question - note that the second address has a space in the name of the city.

Answer (score 0):

This will match all after the `.,`

```
var rs = docs.address.match(/[^\.\,](\w+ ){1,}(\d+)/);
```

Dont match the `.` and `,` then match any word after it, then match the ZIP code